# Crashing when I use navigation bar

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

I'm trying to add a navigation bar to jump from my main view to a second view but I have two problems.

First: the second view is not open at full screen. It's just floating over the first one.
Second: every time I push the back button, which I've change its text to "volver", it crashes.

I've created a function I call when I press a button in the first viewController. My code is below and as you can check I've tried with `dismiss`, `popViewController`, and `popToRoot` but nothing works. I've given the id "RegistroViewController" to my second view.

```
@IBAction func registrarse(_ sender: Any) {
    if let viewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "RegistroViewController") {
        viewController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Volver", style: UIBarButtonItem.Style.plain, target: self, action: #selector(UIWebView.goBack))
        let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: viewController)
        self.present(navController, animated:true, completion: nil)
    }
}

func goBack(){
    //self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    //self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
}
```

The error is:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[eventos.AuthViewController goBack]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ff192c09a80'
> terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
> CoreSimulator 732.17 - Device: iPhone 8 (5334009E-7A5B-4420-A4AD-EC91CB881356) - Runtime: iOS 14.0 (18A372) - DeviceType: iPhone 8

Comment: `self.present` is the cause of your first problem. You can edit it to be presented fullscreen from the bottom, or use `push` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first you have set modelPresentationStyle of a controller  it will show as full screen but will present from bottom to top if you want to change transition style I will also write

```
let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: viewController)
navController.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen // show full screen
// navController.modalTransitionStyle = .crossDissolve // choose whatever
self.present(navController, animated:true, completion: nil)
```

second the crash is due to the selector function

```
UIBarButtonItem(title: "Volver", style: UIBarButtonItem.Style.plain, target: self, action: #selector(UIWebView.goBack))
```

the goBack function must be on RegistroViewController and you can access is

```
UIBarButtonItem(title: "Volver", style: UIBarButtonItem.Style.plain, target: self, action: #selector(viewController.goBack))
```

Comment: You were right about my first mistake thanks. But I've tried to copy the function goback as a function in RegistroViewController and removing from the first view but it stil crashes  Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[eventos.AuthViewController goBack]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fc1fb408cf0'
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: @Monrac The `target` parameter needs to be an instance of the class that actually has the `action` function. If you use `self` then the function must be in the same class.

Comment: Sorry @HangarRash but I think I'm too newby to understand you the code I've copied here It is on my firtstview now I've deleted the func goBack from the first view to the RegistroViewController and the same mistake. Could you give me a bit more of context? sorry for bothering you

Comment: RegistroViewController viewwillappear function are used to assign navigation bar item so remove the viewController.navigationItem. and write it inside RegistroViewController's view will appear function: navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Volver", style: UIBarButtonItem.Style.plain, target: self, action: #selector(goBack)) ; 
and go back function is set @objc func goBack ()

Comment: Ok my mistake I didn´t know how to use the navigation bar. but you were right It was my fault using goback wrongly. Thanks!

Comment: yeah follow a great tutorial will help you alot